# can not specify the content type of MultiPartFile in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send an image to  a server via multiPartRequest in flutter and when I add the image into the request files, once I want to specify the content type which is of MediaType,
a compile-time error appear telling me that MediaType class is not defined.

How can I fix this problem?

```
http.MultipartRequest multipartRequest = new http.MultipartRequest('POST',url);
http.MultipartFile file = new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', await 
image.readAsBytes(),contentType: MediaType('image','jpg));  // MediaType class is not defined
multipartRequest.files.add(file);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out the answer and it is that I must import http parser package

Answer (score 81):

you need to import:

```
 import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';
```

Answer (score 9):

Just check out this if it works

```
uploadFile() async {
    var postUri = Uri.parse("<APIUrl>");
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", postUri);
    request.fields['user'] = 'blah';
    request.files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', await File.fromUri("<path/to/file").readAsBytes(), contentType: new MediaType('image', 'jpeg')))

    request.send().then((response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) print("Uploaded!");
    });
  }
```

Comment: no, I forgot to import http parser package.   thanks for your attempt to help me

Comment: ok, little minor things make things harder, let it be you got the issue that's nice.

Answer (score 0):

add    http_parser: any. to your pub.yaml